# Javafx - child and parent node mouse event

Tags: events, javafx, parent, nodes

I have got a larger Pane (Parent) to which I have added another smaller Pane (Child). I would like to drag the child Pane without dragging the parent Pane (i.e. register mouse event only on the child and not on the parent).
How can we best implement it?

Comment: I am fairly certain adding an `EventHandler<MouseEvent>` to just your child pane would achieve this without having to find a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a work around to my problem.

In the Parent Pane: I used mouseEvent.isControlDown()- So I use crtl+mousebutton down to drag the pane.

In the Child Pane: I used !mouseEvent.isControlDown(). So control keystoke is used to determine which part of the event works.

The parent goes like this:

```
        node.addEventFilter(
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(final MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    if (mouseEvent.isControlDown()) {

                        // remember initial mouse cursor coordinates
                        // and node position
                        dragContext.mouseAnchorX = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
                        dragContext.mouseAnchorY = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
                        dragContext.initialTranslateX
                        = node.getTranslateX();
                        dragContext.initialTranslateY
                        = node.getTranslateY();
                    }
                }
            });
```

The Child goes like this:

```
    node.addEventFilter(
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(final MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    if (!mouseEvent.isControlDown()) {
                        dragContext.mouseAnchorX = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
                        dragContext.mouseAnchorY = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
                        dragContext.initialTranslateX
                        = node.getTranslateX();
                        dragContext.initialTranslateY
                        = node.getTranslateY();
                    }
                }
            });
```